# Referring Variables of type=env in Terraform Cloud Workspace in Terraform Configs

Tags: terraform, environment-variables, terraform-cloud

I have two variables of type "env" in Terraform Cloud.
The two variables are :
"CONFLUENT_CLOUD_API_KEY" & "CONFLUENT_CLOUD_API_SECRET".

I would like to know how do i use the values of these two env vars in my terraform config file in the provider block.
Is the below declaration the right way to use environment variables?

```
provider "confluent" {
 cloud_api_key = ${CONFLUENT_CLOUD_API_KEY}
 cloud_api_secret = ${CONFLUENT_CLOUD_API_SECRET}
}
```

Comment: " Is the below declaration the right way to use environment variables?" - try and see what's going to happen.

Comment: I get this error : Error: Invalid character
on Main.tf line 18, in provider "confluent":
 cloud_api_key = ${CONFLUENT_CLOUD_API_KEY}
This character is not used within the language.

Answer (score 0):

TF environment variables start with `TF_VAR_` as explained in [TF docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables). Also you need `"` around your variables in TF script:

```
provider "confluent" {
 cloud_api_key = "${api_key}"
 cloud_api_secret = "${api_secret}"
}
```